# Jekyll install with Ruby 2.5

Tags: ruby, bundle, jekyll, ffi

I got a problem when i was installing Jekyll on win10.
When I finished deployment for ruby and wanna install Jekyll, it needs to install bundle first.

```
Fetching ffi 1.9.17 (x64-mingw32)
Installing ffi 1.9.17 (x64-mingw32)
Gem::RuntimeRequirementNotMetError: ffi requires Ruby version < 2.5, >= 2.0. The
current ruby version is 2.5.0.
An error occurred while installing ffi (1.9.17), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install ffi -v '1.9.17'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Then I followed the instruction

```
gem install ffi -v 1.9.17
```

The Error log is

```
ERROR:  Error installing ffi:
        The last version of ffi (= 1.9.17) to support your Ruby & RubyGems was 1.9.17. Try installing it with `gem install ffi -v 1.9.17`
        ffi requires Ruby version < 2.5, >= 2.0. The current ruby version is 2.5.0.
```

Also I have tried to followed the solution by [vbortone](https://github.com/ffi/ffi/issues/598).

```
gem install ffi -f
```

It also didn't work.

```
ERROR:  Error installing ffi:
    The last version of ffi (= 1.9.17) to support your Ruby & RubyGems was 1.9.17. Try installing it with `gem install ffi -v 1.9.17`
    ffi requires Ruby version < 2.5, >= 2.0. The current ruby version is 2.5.0.
```

Answer (score 3):

The recent versions of `ffi` installs fine on Ruby 2.5. Bundler automatically requests for the latest version, unless there's a Gemfile.lock file, or a constraint has been specified in a Gemfile file or a dependency's gemspec.

You can first try running `bundle update`.
If that doesn't work, you can edit the Gemfile file (if available), and add `gem 'ffi', '~> 1.9'` before running `bundle install`. You can also manually install the gem with `gem install ffi`.